# Optimize Django tests with preloaded database

Tags: python, django, fixtures, django-testing

I am trying to reduce my CI usage and make my code cleaner by pre-loading my test database using a custom class.

I had multiple files/classes that looked like this:

```py
class TestSomething(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create(...)

    def test_something(self):
        pass
```

I converted them into:

```py
class TestSomething(PreloadedTestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        pass
```

with a common `PreloadedTestCase` class:

```py
class TestSomething(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create(...)
```

This does make the code cleaner and removes a lot of duplicate lines, but it seems to **increase** the CI execution time.

Is `PreloadedTestCase.setUp()` run multiple times? If so, how can I have a common class that is run only once against the database?
I looked into fixtures but it is only populating the database, I would have to query it to access my objects in the tests.

Comment: This is how inheritance works, you aren't loading PreloadedTestCase once then reusing it. You're loading it for every single TestCase instead! As far as im aware there isn't a way to do what you want but if you are able to have prefixed objects in the db and only have to query them instead of create your overall test time should still improve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setUp` runs for each test case, so you're creating the data for each case here.

`setUpClass` runs once for each class (better)

`setUpModule` runs for each module

Don't forget the teardown stuff if you need to.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html

I find `pytest` with `pytest-django` better for this stuff as it makes fixtures easier to use.

Alternatively, you can set up alternative databases to use for Django testing - some good info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/advanced/